# How can I delete autocompletation for React in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm from JetBrains to write my React code. But every time that I write some attribute inside a `<Component>` immediately the IDE adds me curly braces.

For example:

```
<Container
   src={}
>
...
</Container>
```

I don't want to have the curly braces in my code, where can I change this? I was trying to look in JavaScript's and React's configuration, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this behavior:

```
File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Add for JSX attributes
```

The "Add for JSX attributes" setting is under the "Other" tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please try setting **Add for JSX attributes:** to **Quotes** in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other** to have quotes added always, or to **Based on type** to have either braces or quotes auto-completed depending on props type